# expand div onClick

Tags: jquery, css, expand

Hello i am trying to make an expandable div when i'm clicking on a button:
and i want to make the animation with steps, the first step is clicking on the button, the second one the div width expand, and the step 3 the div height expand for get the full page.
and the text inside the div have to change like hide the first text and display the second one when the steps are finish 
Anyone have an idea how to do it?
There is a sketch of the steps i want to make:
[image: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/719800Sanstitre1.jpg]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

requires [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$('.blue').click(function(){
    //expand red div width to 200px
    $('.red').animate({width: "200px"}, 500);
    setTimeout(function(){
        //after 500 milliseconds expand height to 800px
        $('.red').animate({height:"800px"}, 500);
    },500);
    setTimeout(function(){
        //after 1000 milliseconds show textarea (or textbox, span, etc)
        $('.red').find('input[type="textarea"]').show();    
    },1000);
});
```

Comment: thank you that work but the problem is that the div height is going only down like the height dont make an equal expand between up and down, its expanding only 800px to the bottom

Comment: yeah, I suppose you'd have to also change the margin-top accordingly, 

`$('.red').animate({ marginTop: "-350px", height: "800px" }, 500);`

Comment: Do you know how can i fix the scroll of the expand div for make it get all my text area actually i made a new question for it but i didn t get answers:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418811/expand-div-content-scroll

Comment: did you get your answer yet?

Comment: no :( i get an answer but him solution can not make all my text be visible i suppose the problem is that we made a margin top at -400px

Answer (score 3):

This can be done really easily with CSS. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ikye7Qc7Ak&feature=youtu.be&t=763) explains it very well. There are a ton of other neat tricks in that video, but I linked to the part where she explains a light box.

```css
.container {
  padding: 100px;
}
.red,
.blue {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 0;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  transition: 1s height, 1s margin, 1s font-size, 1s 1s width;
}
.blue:focus ~ .red {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: inherit;
  margin-top: -40px;
  transition: 1s width, 1s 1s height, 1s 1s margin, 1s 1s font-size;
}
.red .hint {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 4px;
  transition: 1s 1s font-size;
}
.blue:focus ~ .red .hint {
  font-size: 0;
  transition: 1s font-size;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="blue" tabindex="-1"></div>
  <div class="red"><span class="hint">text1</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah! Using `:focus` is something that didn't occur to me, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Could probably use a `checkbox` with `:checked` too, that way you could toggle by clicking.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $(window).load(function(){
    $(".blue").click(function(){
        $(".red").animate({width:'400px'},1000).animate({height:'400px',top:'150px'},1000).text("qwqwqwq");
    })
})
```

` .blue{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;

```
    }
.red{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: red;
    left:100px;
    }
div{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:300px;

    }`
```