# expand div content scroll

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, expand

Hello i am trying to make a div expanding when i click on a button, and when the expand is done a text appear inside this div so my problem is i can not find a solution to make only my texte be scrollable with the begin at 0% of the top and finish at 100% never mind the size of the window and how can i make a custom scrollbar with only the rectangle of the scrollbar i think an image is more explicite than speak :p 
take a look:

[image]

and there is my code:

```js
$('.button_cadre_about').click(function(){
   //expand red div width to 200px
   $('.hide_open').hide();
   $('.button_cadre_work').hide();
   $('.cadre_home').animate({width: "830px", marginLeft: "-600px",}, 500);
   setTimeout(function(){
    //after 500 milliseconds expand height to 800px
    $('.cadre_home').animate({marginTop: "-400px", marginBottom: "0px", height:"1200px"}, 500);
   },500);
   setTimeout(function(){
    $('#about_btn').find('a').show();
    $('.full_cadre').find('.about_show').show();    
   },1000);
  });
```

```css
body{
 margin:0;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 
}


#container {
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;

}





.full_cadre{
 position:absolute;
 width:460px;
 height:230px;
 background:red;
 text-align:center;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-230px;
 margin-top:-115px;
}

.cadre_home{
 position:absolute;
 width:460px;
 height:230px;
 background:red;
 text-align:center;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-230px;
 margin-top:-115px;
}


.me{
 line-height:10px;
 margin-top:20px;
}


.button_cadre_work, .button_cadre_about{
 cursor:pointer;
}




#about_btn{
 position:absolute;
 top:60%;
 right:-60px;
 color:grey;
 text-align:right;
 z-index:20;

}


#about_btn a{
 position:absolute;
 text-align:right;
 color:grey;
 background:none;
 margin-top:-70px;
 margin-left:80px;
 display:none;
}


.about_show{
 position:absolute;
 width:800px;
 height:100%;
 left:0px;
 margin-top:50px;
 text-align:left;
 color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
 letter-spacing:1px; 
 display:none;
 z-index:99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    
    
        
        
        <div class="full_cadre">
     <div class="cadre_home">
         <div class="hide_open">
                    
                
                   <div class="me"><h1> title </h1><br /> subtitle 
                   </div>
           </div>
           
           <div class="about_show">
                      <h2>SALUT</h2>
                          <p>Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker.
                          </p>
                          <h2>SALUT</h2>
                          <p>Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker.
                          </p><br><br><br>
                          <h2>SALUT</h2>
                          <p>Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker.
                          </p>
                    </div>
         </div>
           <div id="button_cadre">
            
             <div class="button_cadre_about"><div id="about_btn"><a href="#"><p>X</p></a><span>CLICK</span></div>
                
              </div>
            
           </div>
        </div>
    
  </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ok but the full windows has not scrollbar because my body is in overflow hidden what i want is to make a "div" scrollable ...

Comment: it' s work but i can' t get all the text

Comment: i think the problem is when i expand my ... $('.cadre_home').animate({marginTop: "-400px", marginBottom: "0px", height:"1200px"}, 500);
   },500);      the div is at -400px from the top :/ so i try to know how can i make my div get the 100% of the content manually :p

Comment: if it' s work good ... why not ;p

Answer (score 0):

I appologize for not using your code, but I think this clean example should help answer some of your questions, let me know if theres anything you're still unsure about.

```
#content {
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nncLcyym/